# Specflow testing Flash UI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, flash, apache-flex, specflow

We have a web application that has a flash UI for which we would like to write automated tests. Does anyone know if this is possible using Specflow and Visual Studio?

Comment: Wouldn't a simple review of Specflow docs answer this question?  The tools for UI testing of a Flash App [that I know of] are MonkeyTalk, RIATest, and QTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpecFlow is a framework for creating acceptance tests. Underneath SpecFlow steps you can run whatever you want: Selenium, WPF UI test, etc. In other words SpecFlow doesn't have any build-in support for any kind of tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS2010 or VS2012 and you really wanted to do the UI side of the automation, you could use MS Coded UI tests with MSTest. If you build out your UI tests in a very modular way, you could use SpecFlow to kickoff the various UI tests and drive scenarios.